# Xcode breakpoints for single device only?

Tags: debugging, xcode5, breakpoints

Is it possible to restrict breakpoints in Xcode 5.1 to be effective only one one device if several (e.g. iPhone plus iPad during development of Game Center app) are connected to Mac?

Comment: You can have different schemes in Xcode for that as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @SergiusGee that sounds promising. Can you explain a bit more (in an answer perhaps)? I just copied my scheme and launched the app on two devices using the original and copied scheme respectively. However, if I toggle breakpoints it always seems to affect both devices still.

Answer (score 0):

Not the simplest solution in the word, but this is the first thing that comes to mind:

Right-click the breakpoint, choose "Edit", and in the "Condition" field add something like this:

```
(BOOL)[some condition that is true only on the relevant device]
```

Edit: Note that the compiler for conditional breakpoints does not support the instance.something syntax for property getter. You should only use use [instance something].